# Alias for std::dynamic_pointer_cast

Tags: c++, c++11, templates

I'm trying to create an alias for `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` but can't write something that compiles.

This is the way I'm trying:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
using dcast = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T1, T2>;
```

What is wrong with it?

Compiler errors:

gcc: `dynamic_pointer_cast' in namespace 'std' does not name a type'`

clang: `no type named 'dynamic_pointer_cast' in namespace 'std'`

VS: `syntax error: identifier 'dynamic_pointer_cast'`

Try it: https://godbolt.org/g/akbqiu

EDIT: As Brian pointed out, you can only alias types not functions.

I've tried with the following code:

```
template <typename T1, typename T2>
auto& dcast = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T1, T2>;
```

Which seems to compile on itself, but once you try to call it it gives the following error:

```
error: wrong number of template arguments (1, should be 2)
```

You can call `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` with only one template argument though. Which could be the alternative?

Comment: What errors you are getting?

Comment: You can only create aliases for types, not for functions.

Comment: @Brian Ah, I see, that makes sense

Comment: Perhaps a template function which just calls `std::dynamic_pointer_cast`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in comments, you have to make a new function:

```
template <class T, class U> 
std::shared_ptr<T> dcast(const std::shared_ptr<U> &r) noexcept
{
    return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<T>(r);
}
```

Comment: Thanks, it seems to work. J̶u̶s̶t̶ ̶h̶a̶d̶ ̶t̶o̶ ̶r̶e̶m̶o̶v̶e̶ ̶`̶n̶o̶e̶x̶c̶e̶p̶t̶`̶ ̶s̶i̶n̶c̶e̶ ̶I̶'̶m̶ ̶u̶s̶i̶n̶g̶ ̶C̶+̶+̶1̶4̶

Comment: @tuket Then why did you mark the question as c++11?

Comment: Sorry I though `noexcept` was a C++17 feature. I labeled it as C++11 because `std::dynamic_pointer_cast` is a C++11 feature. Thanks!